# Migrations Error - cannot scaffold literals of type DirectConstructorBinding

Tags: ef-core-2.0

I'm following the Pluralsight Course by Julie Lerman -- `EntityFramework Core 2: Getting Started`. In this course, she has 3 projects. The first two `Data` and `Domain` are based on the .NET Standard library. The third project `Web` is a .NET Core Web Application.

I've followed this structure. In `Data` I added one POCO class called Client.

In `Domain` I added one class called TestDbContext like so:

```
public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }

    public TestDbContext(DbContextOptions<TestDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
}
```

Following her example, I did the following in the Startup.cs of my `Web` project to inject the provider and connection string into the DbContext.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddMvc();
   services.AddDbContext<TestDbContext>(options =>
   {
       options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TestConnection"));
   });
}
```

Lastly, I attempt to add a migration to this context. I have the `Web` project set as the startup project. From the Package Manager Console, I type `add-migration initial`.

I then get the following error: `The current CSharpHelper cannot scaffold literals of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.DirectConstructorBinding'.  Configure your services to use one that can.`

In Julie's video, this all worked for her and the migration package was created. However, for me -- just the error. Any clues as to what may be going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check packages version of your project in  '.csproj' file. Previously I have the same problem for version mitch match of **AspNet Core** and **EntityFramework Core** (I guess). Making those same works for me fine. Found solution [Here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11177)

For me Now.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.0-rc1-final" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.0-rc1-final" PrivateAssets="All" />
```

Comment: That was it.  I was targeting .netcoreapp2.0, but the EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer was version 2.1.0.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Add 3 packages with same version from nuget package manager

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.2" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This did the trick for me!

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<DotNetCliToolReference  Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.1.0- preview1-final" />
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Trick worked for me too. it saved lot of time. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Install plugin **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design** in to the Database Project (Where ***dbcontext*** class created project)

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

->Open the WebApp .csproj file and make the changes below:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Now becomes:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

->Install the latest Microsoft.AspNetCore.App from nugget package into the Web App

->Comment out this line:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.9" />
```

->Edit the StartUp.cs file by commenting out "app.UseBrowserLink()"
->Recompile the solution

->Add Migration: add-migration initial

Happy coding...